# Bootstrap Checkbox- how do I return typed-in value?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

I'm building an application at work, and one requirement is a select box that also allows typing in a string of your own. [Bootstrap Combobox](https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox) seemed to do exactly that. I'm using Bootstrap 4.

Now, this is the code in my View (simplified due to NDA reasons):

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    actionName: "Testcombo",
    controllerName: "Backoffice",
    ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST"
    }
    ))
    {

    <select class="combobox" name="TestDrop">
        <option></option>
        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    </select>

    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Press</button>
    </div>
    }

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.combobox').combobox();
    });
</script>
```

As is clear, it should return the variable TestDrop to the Controller. And when I pick any of the prewritten dropdown options, the Controller does receive the proper value.

However, when I type in a string value of my own and press the button, I get an empty string back. TestDrop = "" is the result.

What should I do to get the desired result, i.e. the written value? Please assist. Thank you.

Comment: 'Should' this even be possible? A combobox should provide a list of options - take one or leave. When the city 'Ironforge' is not in that list, you can not select it. Period. ... maybe you need a different control like `typeahead`?